# Get name of controls for MouseDown and DragDrop

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop, mouse

I have a VB.net Windows form with a grid of Button controls. How best to capture the name of the buttons for a drag and drop operation? If I know the names of the source and destination buttons I can take appropriate action.

Comment: Hard to be specific without seeing any code, but within your event handlers you just cast the sender object to a control type and then you have access to all the usual properties...including their names

Comment: Why would you need the names when you have the `Buttons` themselves?  The `sender` parameter in the event handler IS the `Button`.  If you really do need the name, which I very much doubt, then you'd get it from the `Name` property of the `Button` you already have.

Comment: Each button is linked to specific variable values. A simple example would be Button1 relates to "Dog", Button2 relates to "Cat". If Button1 is selected for drag and Drop to Button2, I just need to set Button2 to "Dog". So my idea was if I knew the respective control names I could easily make the change.

Comment: Please we need to see some code in order to help you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the destination button and source button from arguments to the DragDrop handler

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' If buttons are on Panel1 then 
    '     Me.Panel1.Controls().OfType(Of Button)()
    ' If buttons share some unique substring in name (to exclude other buttons)
    '     Me.Controls().OfType(Of Button)().Where(Function(b) b.Name.Contains("substring"))
    Dim myButtons = Me.Controls().OfType(Of Button)()
    ' add all the event handlers to the buttons in the list
    For Each b In myButtons
        b.AllowDrop = True
        AddHandler b.DragDrop, AddressOf Button_DragDrop
        AddHandler b.DragEnter, AddressOf Button_DragEnter
        AddHandler b.MouseMove, AddressOf Button_MouseMove
    Next
End Sub

' standard event handler for drag enter
Private Sub Button_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs)
    If TypeOf e.Data.GetData(e.Data.GetFormats()(0)) Is Button Then e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move
End Sub

' standard event handler for mouse move related to drag drop
Private Sub Button_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then DoDragDrop(sender, DragDropEffects.Move)
End Sub

' the key is getting the source and destination from the arguments
Private Sub Button_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs)
    Dim destinationButton = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim sourceButton = DirectCast(e.Data.GetData(e.Data.GetFormats()(0)), Button)
    MessageBox.Show($"Source: {sourceButton.Name}, Destination: {destinationButton.Name}")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: I added a DrageLeave event and code to alter the appearance of the buttons as the mouse moves over them. Only problem I am having now is originally I had a Click event that when fired launched a form where the user could make some decisions. The new events are firing before the Click event, how best to deal with this?