# Using a property of the Sender object for MouseMove Handler for Drag Drop

Tags: windows, vb.net, forms, drag-and-drop, mouseevent

I'm sorry the question isn't clearer.  I was setting up some drag drop based on code in this post.  [Get name of controls for MouseDown and DragDrop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57908418/get-name-of-controls-for-mousedown-and-dragdrop)

The two controls I am using are different.  The source is a list and the destination is text.  To capture the row of text I want from the list I need to use the .selectedText property.

```
     '''
     C1List1.DoDragDrop(C1List1.SelectedText, DragDropEffects.Copy)
     '''
```

Is there a way to make it generic for any list control?  '''sender.selectedText''' obviously doesn't work but something like this that will work is what I'm looking for.

```
    '''C1List1.DoDragDrop(Sender.SelectedText, DragDropEffects.Copy)'''
```

Comment: What is a "list control" anyway? There's a `ListControl` class that is the base for `ListBox` and `ComboBox` but it doesn't have a `SelectedText` property. You can only use members that objects actually have. You can't pluck them out of thin air. What controls are you actually talking about? You need to use the appropriate property of each of those controls, whatever that may be.

Comment: Actually, the fact that your control is named `C1List1` suggests that it is a ComponentOne control. That's something that you might mention explicitly, rather than assuming that we'll know what third-party control you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sender` parameter is type `Object` in a proper event handler, so if you want to use it as some other type then you need to cast as that type, e.g. `DirectCast(sender, ListControl)`. You can then access members of that type on that reference.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!

Comment: @DeanBashore Note that `DirectCast` will throw if the object isn't of the right type (or something derived from it).  If you're not sure, you can use `TryCast` instead.